# What is the cardinality of this absolutely outrageous set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity, indeterminate-forms

Burning question. Consider the following set: $$A=\left\{\frac{0}{0},\frac{\infty}{\ \infty},\ 0\cdot\infty,\ 1^{\infty},\ \infty-\infty,\ 0^{0},\ \infty^{0}\right\}$$

The A stands for Any Self-Respecting Mathematician's Worst Nightmare. Anyway, if I wanted to know $|A|$, which I sure do, how would I find it? Is $A$ a set of seven indeterminate forms, and therefore $|A|=7$? Or is $A$ equivalent to $\emptyset$ because the **quotient** of $0$ and $0$ and the **product** of $0$ and $\infty$ are not things at all? Or, is $|A|=7$ because $A$ is a set containing 7 empty subsets? Send help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way overthinking this here.  The fact that the elements are not defined numbers is no problem at all, they are still perfectly good as elements.  Thus $A$ is a set of indeterminate forms with cardinality $7$.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B0%2F0%2C+%E2%88%9E%5E0%7D%3D%E2%88%85) seems to think there's more to it than that.

Comment: They try to fit the elements with defined numbers.  But they don't have to be so in order to function as elements of a set.